# How long would it take to for society to return to normal after a devastating 40 to 50% loss of population?

Tags: society

We often see in various alien invasion movies or natural catastrophes movies, where all our famous landmarks are smashed to pieces, that lots of people die.
In lots of movies it shows life returning to relatively normal and society recovering fairly quickly afterwards.
Well lets say something like that happened, aliens invasion happens and we beat them. Or some giant natural catastrophe or a pandemic sweeps the Earth. Either way 40 to 50% of the world´s population kicks the bucket so let´s use the current population of earth 7,8 billion so that´s about 3,9 billion people on a global level that dies and lets say those deaths are more or less equally divided among each country in the world, before its all over (we win against the threat, we gain enough immunity to the virus for the herd immunity to set in or the natural catastrophe is over) and rebuilding can begin.

My question is how long would it actually take our infrastructure and society to return to the same level as it was before the disaster.

Comment: Hi, @Gridlock, welcome to Worldbuilding SE! Could you be more specific about what "return to normal" mean? In real life, some countries suffered major population losses because of war. In some aspects, life returned to normal rather quickly. In others, their societies were scarred for generations.

Comment: You need to be more specific, if 40/50% of the world dies out it matters if it's in a single area like Asia or globally. Also the cause would heavily impact the results like were it killer robots? zombies? a plague? meteors?  because the population loss would not be the biggest issue. Biggest issue would be the collapse of infrastructure.

Comment: Hello Gridlock. Welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. You're asking what we call a [high concept question](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4868), which isn't a good fit for our site. "Normal" is very different between blocks in the same city, much less nations around the world, and that ignores the thousands and thousands of details that would be needed to answer such a question. Justifying an answer would be writing an entire book.  VTC:Needs-Details.

Comment: The [Black Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Death) of the mid-14th century did indeed kill some 40% to 50% of the population of Western Europe; what does your historical research say about the time that Western Europe took to bounce back to normal life and development?

Comment: One more thing. This doesn't quite feel like a worldbuilding question. It feels more like a whimsical, "I was just thinking..." question. What is your worldbuilding context? Are you writing a story about an alien invasion? Details about your worldbuilding goals would help a lot.

Comment: I have seen alot of world ending stories and most of them have humanity bounce back to a pre-disater status in no time. 
I am looking for a more realistic take on how bad such a disaster would hit us and how long we would be to return from such a large catastrophe.

Comment: Problem with the black death as a parable is that back in those days people weren´t as global as we are now, and not quite as specialized as we are now. 
So i am looking for a more modern version of how long a society would take to recover from such a disaster.

Comment: JBH, a good portion of the questions I have asked have just been me wondering about something fairly world-building related, even if it is not part of an actual world.

Comment: I think the definition of "back to normal" is really subjective and needs clarifying. Rationing after ww2 continued until 1954. The Dow Jones index recovered after 911 by Christmas, but low flying planes near Manhattan still trigger PTSD.

Comment: @meaninglessname, I have asked such questions, too, but I try to keep them in the context of building a world. This question has no background and no goals. The time needed to "bounce back" could be a week or centuries depending on what the OP needs for his/her world. There needs to be a purpose or it's not a worldbuilding question (and there's plenty of closed questions to underscore that).

Comment: Here's the problem: if "normal" means "same population as before" then it took about 50 years to double the population to today. If "normal" means "I live my life with the same comfort" it will take a LOT LESS time because all that know-how exists and we just need to get factories going at lower volumes. If "normal" means "first to get back to normal" then it will take about a week for a pacific islander to overcome the shock and go pick more coconuts. If the cause of the problem was a disease, it may take centuries to get back. If most of the deaths were the elderly, we're back tomorrow.

Comment: Oh, Gridlock... if you tag someone in your comment (e.g., @Gridlock), that person will be notified of the comment. You can only tag one user per comment. Otherwise we have to come back to see how the conversation is going, and that's pretty random.

Comment: @Ash:  WWII rationing lasted until 1954 in Britain.  That was arguably political, the result of the British voting in a Labour government.  In the US, rationing other than sugar ended with the war, in August 1945.

Comment: You ask about infrastructure in your final question, but that's a bit of a separate question from population. A mega-pandemic for instance may drastically cut your population, but the physical infrastructure of the world will still exist (minus any degradation due to skipped maintenance), whereas a massive orbital bombardment from an alien invasion will result in destruction of physical infrastructure on a completely different scale.

Comment: The technology level matters greatly here.  As has been said, the black death was a kill of this level and it didn't take that long to bounce back.  A 40-50% kill now would be on the verge of an extinction event and probably would **never** return to normal.

Comment: I see this hasn't been edited since October last, and it still has at least two separate questions (of population and of infrastructure). It also doesn't clarify what kìnd of disaster this is. Some disasters will leave infrastructure entirely intact, others will severely damage or destroy. For now, this should remain closed.